# Regionale Verbreitung von »Ich bin Hauptplatz«

Tags: usage, regional

Wenn man in Wien mit öffentlichen Verkehrsmittel fährt, hört man zwangsweise einige Telefonate mit, die die Fahrgäste mit ihren Gesprächspartnern führen. Dabei ist naturgemäß der aktuelle Aufenthaltsort des Fahrgastes ein häufiges Thema, und an U-Bahn-Stationen oder Straßenbahnhaltestellen hört man - zumindest in Wien - sehr oft so etwas:

> Ich bin gleich da. **Ich bin Stephansplatz.** Die U-Bahn kommt in 2 Minuten.
>
> **Ich bin Stadion.** Wo bist du?
>
> Hallo, **ich bin Heinestraße** und warte auf die Straßenbahn.
>
> **Ich bin Simmering.**
>
> **Ich bin Stubentor.**
>
> usw.

Es wird also formal behauptet, selbst eine bestimmte U-Bahn-Station oder Straßenbahn- bzw. Bus-Haltestelle zu sein. Tatsächlich ist natürlich gemeint, dass man sich gerade dort aufhält, was gemäß der üblichen Grammatik aber die Verwendung von Präpositionen erfordern würde, die dem jeweiligen Ort entsprechen müssten:

> Ich bin **am** Stephansplatz.
>   Ich bin **beim** Stadion.
>   Ich bin **bei der** Heinestraße.
>   Ich bin **in** Simmering.
>   Ich bin **beim** Stubentor.

Alternativ könnte man auch sagen:

> Ich bin **in der Station** »Stephansplatz«.
>   Ich bin **an der Haltestelle** »Heinestaße«.
>   usw.

Das hört man in Wien aber so gut wie nie.

Meine Frage ist nun, ob die Konstruktion »Ich bin <*Stationsname*>« ein alleiniges Wiener Phänomen ist, oder ob die Benutzer öffentlicher Verkehrsmittel auch anderswo die Präpositionen einfach weglassen wenn sie ihren Standort bekanntgeben.

---

### nachträgliche Ergänzungen

**Nicht nur öffentlicher Verkehr**
Die Konstruktion »Ich bin <*Ortsangabe*>« hört man natürlich besonders oft, wenn Fahrgäste eines öffentlichen Verkehrsmittels per Mobiltelefon ihren Standort an den Gesprächspartner melden. Die Verwendung dieser Konstruktion ist aber nicht an dieses eine Szenario gebunden. Auch Fußgänger, fern von Haltestellen, benutzen sie (»Ich bin Haupteingang, neben Portier« oder »Ich bin Kino«). Allerdings tritt an diesen Orten das Bedürfnis seinen Aufenthaltsort zu melden offenbar seltener auf, so dass aus diesem Grund diese Konstruktion abseits des öffentlichen Verkehrs seltener zu hören ist.

**Bei Antworten/Kommentaren bitte beachten**
Ich habe um eine Schilderung der regionalen Verteilung gebeten. Antworten wie »das ist ein Großstadtphänomen« mögen zwar vielleicht wahre Aussagen sein (was ich aber bezweifle wenn ich höre, dass München und Dresden nicht betroffen sind), aber sie beantworten die gestellte Frage nicht. Ich bitte darum, die Namen ganz konkreter Städte oder Regionen zu nennen. Hilfreich wären auch Negativ-Meldungen. Also: Wo wurde man mehrfach Ohrenzeuge von Positionsmeldungen, bei denen die Konstruktion »Ich bin <*Ortsangabe*>« nicht verwendet wurde.

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Umfragen und "List Questions" sind für das Stack Exchange Format grundsätzlich nicht geeignet, da man kaum eine "richtige" Antwort erhalten kann, und da es ja auch nicht um die Lösung eines Problems geht. Das zeigen auch die Antworten und Komentare die wir hier haben. Ich habe eine CW-Antwort generiert, in die man seinen Ort eintragen kann, wenn man möchte.

Comment: Interessant ist, daß man diese Entwicklung auch im Griechischen beobachtet. Ich würde sagen «πάω σπίτι/είμαι σπίτι»(ich gehe Haus/ich bin ein Haus) ist häufiger als die Variante mit Präposition und klingt nicht mehr gossig. Gleiches gilt für σχολείο (Schule). Seit einigen Jahrzehnten dehnt sich das Muster aus...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Hier wird die Präposition häufig weggelassen:

- **Hamburg** hier. Die gefühlte Verbreitung unter S-Bahn-Insassen ist ca. 100% [user comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2784/kilian-foth)
- Das ist nicht nur im Bereich öffentliche Verkehrsmittel hier in **Hessen** sehr verbreitet. Generell sind sprachliche Undinge wie "Ich geh mal Aldi" hier an der Tagesordnung. Leider.[user comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2072/thorsten-dittmar)
- **Wien, Berlin.** In Linz hingegen habe ich das noch nie gehört (bin aus der Gegend). Persönlich würde ich das auch nie sagen, es klingt einfach extrem falsch für mich. [user comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/15370/bernd)
- Und noch ein paar Variationen aus **Berlin** (da es nicht auf "sein" beschränkt ist) "Komma Ringcenter" "Lass ma Alex fahren" "Ich komm Görli." "Thomas wohnt Alex." [user comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1362/emanuel)
- In **Braunschweig** wurden, nachdem der aktive Benutzer angefangen hat, darauf zu achten, zweimal derartige Konstruktionen gehört (»Wir müssen Paxmann raus«, »Ich bin Siekgraben«; beides sind Haltestellen von Bus bzw. Tram). Stichprobengröße *n* = 2

### Hier wird die Präposition selten weggelassen:

- noch nie gehört (**München und Dresden**) [user comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/9091/matthias)
- Ich habe diesen Satzbau hier (**Südwestdeutschland**) ehrlich gesagt noch nie gehört, wenn er nicht gleichzeitig mit einem starken Akzent begleitet war. Durchaus bei Jugendlichen vermutlich unterschiedlichster Herkunft, aber noch nie bei jemandem (inklusive Jugendlichen), der hörbar akzentfrei gesprochen hat.[user comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/5999/o-r-mapper)
- In **Köln** bin ich immer zu Fuß oder mit dem Auto unterwegs, aber ich wage zu behaupten, da sagt das kein Schwein so. [user comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1224/em1)

Answer (score 15):

Ich kann nur für Berlin sprechen – und hier ist es ziemlich üblich geworden. Besonders amüsant ist diese Konstruktion bei (absichtlich) gekürzten Stationsnamen:

- "Ich bin **am Alexanderplatz**" –> "Ich bin **Alex**"
- "Ich bin **am Rosenthaler Platz**" –> "Ich bin **Rosi**"

Das wird hier auch gerne auf Bezirke ausgeweitet, was dem ganzen einen Hauch von Lokalpatriotismus verleiht und mit der Berliner Image-Kampagne [*Sei Berlin!*](http://www.sei.berlin.de/kampagne) korrespondiert:

- "Ich bin Kreuzberg", "Ich bin Mitte" etc.

Mein Allzeitfavorit:

- "Ich bin an der Ecke zur Ackerstrasse" –> "**Icke Ecke Acker**"

Comment: +1 für Icke Ecke Acker :D

Comment: Also "Ecke ZUR Ackerstrasse" hat gloobick hundat Jahre keena mea jesagt. Und wowa schoma dabei sind... "Ich bin Anne Acker" jeht och.

Comment: Und noch ein paar Variationen aus Berlin (da es nicht auf "sein" beschränkt ist)  "Komma Ringcenter" "Lass ma Alex fahren" "Ich komm Görli." "Thomas wohnt Alex."

Answer (score 7):

Ich habe in den Achtzigerjahren ein Westberliner Gymnasium mit verschwindend geringem, wie man damals sagte, Ausländeranteil besucht und seitdem die meiste Zeit in Berlin gewohnt.

Als ich die Überschrift gelesen habe, kam mir das Beispiel sehr falsch vor. Das liegt aber vor allem daran, dass ich „Hauptplatz“ nicht als Haltestelle erkannt habe. Hingegen habe ich kürzlich

> Ich bin jetzt Gesundbrunnen, ...

in einer Kurznachricht verwendet. Der Unterschied ist, dass mir und dem Empfänger klar ist, dass „Gesundbrunnen“ eine Haltestelle bezeichnet. Außerdem habe ich das Gefühl, dass eine Zeitangabe wie „jetzt“ oder „gleich“ den Satz zumindest für mich idiomatischer macht.

Ich denke, der Grund dafür, dass ich das akzeptabel finde, und auch dafür, dass ich denke, dass man hier Haltestellen und Bahnhöfe von anderen Ortsangaben getrennt betrachten sollte, ist, dass eine keine Präposition gibt, die passen würde, sondern die gesamte Phrase „im Bahnhof“ eingefügt werden müsste, die doch recht redundant ist. So wäre

> Ich bin jetzt am Gesundbrunnen, ...

sicher faktisch falsch, und ich weiß nicht mal, ob es einen solchen noch gibt. Und

> Ich bin jetzt in Gesundbrunnen, ...

wäre zwar richtig (Gesundbrunnen ist ein Ortsteil), aber nicht der Punkt.

Auf der gleichen Fahrt habe ich (fragt nicht warum ich mehrfach versucht habe, meine Position mitzuteilen)

> Ich bin jetzt Osloer Straße.

geschrieben. Auch da war ich nicht in der Osloer Straße, ich war in einem Tunnel!

Comment: Ich glaube, in Zukunft schreibe ich nur noch grammatisch richtig „ich bin in einem Tunnel“.

Comment: Darf man fragen in welchem Jahrzehnt du geboren bist?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, reicht es nicht, wenn ich schreibe, dass ich in den 80ern die Oberschule besucht habe? Aber wenn Du so indiskret fragst :) Ich bin knapp vor Beginn der 70er geboren ;) Wir sind also quasi im gleichen Alter.

Comment: Sorry, habe ich überlesen. Danke für deine Antwort! Damit bist du ein Gegenbeispiel für die These, diese Konstruktion würde nur von Migranten und Jugendlichen verwendet. Da deine Reputation in diesem Forum bereits über 4000 Punkten liegt, kann man auch kein Desinteresse an deiner Muttersprache vermuten. Deine im Profil verlinkte Homepage weist dich auch als Hochschul-Mathematiker aus, also trifft bei dir auch das Argument »ungebildet« nicht zu. Das ist interessant und nährt meine These, dass diese Konstruktion längst auch schon bei den einheimischen gebildeten Erwachsenen angekommen ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, leider kann ich nicht sagen, ob ich diese Konstruktion auch schon vor 25 Jahren benutzt habe oder ob sie sich eingeschlichen hat. Das würde mich auch interessieren. Ich würde sie aber eher nicht für neu halten und daher von dem allgemeinen Präpositionsschwund, den hier einige beklagen, trennen.

Comment: Ich (akad. geb., knapp 40, Wien) verwende sie auch, aber eben _nur_ im Zusammenhang mit U-Bahn-Stationen udgl. "Ich bin Wien Mitte" ist in Ordnung, wenn ich die U-Bahn dort verlasse bin ich in _der_ Landstraßer Hauptstraße und gehe _in den_ Stadtpark.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Bin gerade durch eine Verlinkung einer anderen Frage hierher gekommen und erkenne große Ähnlichkeiten zwischen Carsten und mir (Alter, Bildungsgrad, Wohnort), er ist somit kein Einzelfall. Gefühlt würde ich sagen, dass ich derartige Verkürzungen bei Haltestellennamen als Ortsangabe seit mindestens 30 Jahren benutze.

Comment: @CarstenS Könntest Du bitte die Ortsangabe von der DDR-Schreibweise *Westberliner* in das korrekte *West-Berliner* abändern? - Sonst muss ich mir überlegen, den Upvote doch wieder rückgängig zu machen...

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf, dazu sehe ich keinen Anlass.

Comment: @CarstenS Die von Dir benutzte Schreibweise kommt normalerweise bei Leuten vor, die zu einer von 3 Gruppen gehören: 1) Menschen, die in der DDR geboren und aufgewachsen sind und dann das einmal erlernte beibehalten (auch wenn sie eventuell schon als ältere Kinder/Jugendliche nach Berlin (West) gekommen sind. 2) Menschen, die es nicht besser wissen, weil sie z.B. weit weg von Berlin aufgewachsen sind. 3) Menschen, die zwar aus dem Westen stammen, aber ideologisch der DDR und der Idee von der "selbständigen politischen Einheit" anhängen. Zur zweiten Gruppe dürftest Du wohl eher nicht gehören...

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Ich schreibe auch nicht West-Frankreich.  Der kalte Krieg ist vorbei.

Comment: @CarstenS *Der kalte Krieg ist vorbei* - warum verwendest Du dann einen Begriff, den die DDR in eben jenem Kalten Krieg kreiert hat, um das Trennende zu betonen, und der im Westen niemals korrekte oder - außerhalb gewisser Kreise - akzeptierte Schreibweise war?

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass das hier der richtige Ort für eine politische Diskussion ist. (Mir war bis gerade eben auch gar nicht bewusst, dass es zwischen Westberlin und West-Berlin einen politischen Unterschied gibt. Ich bin in der Oststeiermark, die zu Ostösterreich gehört aufgewachsen, und weder mit diesen Schreibweisen nich mit Ost-Steirermark oder Ost-Österreich ein Problem.

Answer (score 5):

Scheint ein Großstadtphänomen zu sein und vermutlich auch nur unter den jüngeren Bewohnern gebräulich. Ich vermute diese Ausdrucksweise wurde stark von Immigranten beeinflusst und später von den Kids aufgegriffen. Selbiges ist bei "Gemma DZ?" (Gehen wir zum/ins Donauzentrum?) zu beobachten.

Comment: Großstadtphänomen, naja: es braucht zumindest eine U-Bahn, S-Bahn, Straßenbahn oder ähnliche Verkehrsmittel, wobei das auch im Zug ganz gut funktioniert ("Wo bist du?" "Ich bin gerade St. Veit"). Es stimmt zwar, dass zB das Türkische mW Präpositionen in unserem Sinn nicht kennt, aber diese Ausdrucksweise hat damit nichts zu tun, es ist einfach eine Verkürzung von "Ich bin gerade (in der Station) Stephansplatz". Nachdem ich die U-Bahn verlassen habe befinde ich mich selbstverständlich _am_ Stephansplatz. (Mit knapp 40 gehöre ich übrigens auch nicht mehr wirklich zu den Kids.)

Comment: @Bernd: Von welchen Großstädten sprichst du konkret? Nenne bitte die Namen der Orte wo du das häufig gehört hast, und ergänze das auch um Orte wo du das nicht gehört hast, denn sonst beantwortet deine Antwort nicht meine Frage.

Comment: Wien, Berlin. In Linz hingegen habe ich das noch nie gehört (bin aus der Gegend). Persönlich würde ich das auch nie sagen, es klingt einfach extrem falsch für mich.

Comment: Nein, ist kein Großstadtphänomen. Komme aus einer Kleinstadt in Hessen ohne Straßen-/UBahn. Hier heißt es dann eben "Ich geh Aldi" oder "Ich bin Sport".

Comment: _Das_ ist dann aber wohl auf gewisse Bevölkerungsschichten und -kreise beschränkt und kein universelles Phänomen, nehme ich an? "Ich mach dich Messer" hat es ja auch noch nicht in den Duden geschafft.

Answer (score 5):

Scheint (egal ob Großstadt oder nicht) ein Phänomen der Jugendsprache zu sein. "Konstruktionen" wie

> Ich geh Aldi, wo Du?

Oder

> Gehst Du Deutsch? Nee, kein Bock.

hört man wohl an fast jeder Schule heute.

Comment: »Deutsch« ist aber nicht unbedingt eine Ortsangabe. Ich finde, dass Meinungsäußerungen zwar erlaubt sein sollen, aber nicht in Antworten gehören. Man kann sein Herz (oder Organe des Verdauungsapparats) ja auch in einem Kommentar ausschütten. Ich finde, Antworten sollten sachlich sein und die gestellte Frage beantworten. Nicht ohne Grund sind Fragen, die gezielt nach Meinungen fragen, hier auch nicht erlaubt.

Comment: "Deutsch" im Sinne von "Deutschunterricht" ist aber in dem Sinne der Aussage auch ein Zielpunkt oder Aufenthaltsort. Die Aussagen "Ich bin im Deutschunterricht" oder "Ich gehe in den Deutschunterricht" finde ich durchaus äquivalent zu "Ich bin am Alex" oder "Ich gehe zum Potsdamer Platz".

Comment: Dies ist ein gutes Beispiel dafür, dass das Weglassen von Präpositionen vielleicht eher ein allgemeines Phänomen der **Jugendsprache** ist und deshalb gar nicht auf Ortsangaben in der U-Bahn oder auf verschiedene Großstädte begrenzt werden kann. **Evtl. sollte man die Frage dahingehend anpassen**. In meiner Altersgruppe (50+) wird es jedenfalls nur passiv verstanden und oft gehört aber aktiv kaum benutzt.

Comment: Ebenso werden andere Sätze wie z.B. "Kann ich Kartoffeln?" für "Kann ich noch Kartoffeln haben?" verwendet; reine Jugendsprache, allerdings seit 10-15 Jahren zu hören und manche werden das nicht mehr los, so daß auch Erwachsene sich inzwischen so äußern/outen..

Comment: Das Argument ist ja immer, dass man auch "Ich kann Englisch" sagen kann. Was die Sprecher hierbei übersehen, ist, dass in einem Fall "können" im Sinne von "fähig sein" verwenden (benötigt kein Hilfsverb), im anderen Fall jedoch im Sinne von "dürfen", und "dürfen" benötigt ein Hilfsverb. Meine Standardantwort hierauf ist übrigens "Vollende das Prädikat".

Answer (score 4):

Hier in Stuttgart hört man diese Verkürzungen ebenfalls, ich würde aber eher sagen, dass es etwa die Hälfte der Fahrgäste sind, und eher jüngere.

Die Vermutung, dass es von "Migrantendeutsch" hergeleitet sein könnte, scheint mir vertretbar.
Begünstigt dürfte die scheinbar wachsende Verbreitung dadurch werden, dass eine solche Variante auch kürzer ist, und ich mich zu erinnern meine, gelesen zu haben, dass zum Beispiel Anglizismen besonders dort Verwendung finden, wo sie kürzer sind als die "Originalsprache".

Möglicherweise hat die Gewöhnung an (kurze) Textnachrichten ebenfalls einen Einfluss.

Comment: Ortsangaben werden schon länger ohne Präposition adverbial gebraucht, außer man zählt *Höhe, Ecke* usw. als Präpositive, bspw. "Der Lastwagen fuhr auf der Hauptstraße. *Höhe Bahnhofstraße* kam er ins schleudern." Das ist wortwörtlich trivial. Eine passende Präposition für "Wir nähern uns dem Zielort" gibt es z.B. gar nicht, wobei "dem Zielort" durch den Ortsnamen ersetzt werden kann und ein passender Fall wie Lokativ oder Ablativ(?) auch nicht existiert.