# Negative Antwort mit positiver Alternative geben

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Diese Frage lässt sich am besten mit Hilfe einiger Beispiele erklären.

> A: Fahren alle Busse von dieser Haltestelle über Hauptbahnhof?
>   B: Nein, aber [die 42 ja/die 42 ja schon/die 42 fährt/die 42 doch schon].

Was stellt man da zwischen die eckigen Klammern, um kurz und idiomatisch auszudrücken, dass die 42 über Hauptbahnhof fährt?

Ich suche also die deutsche Entsprechung für die folgenden englischen bzw. französischen Sätze:

> ‘No, but the 42 does.’
>   « Non, mais le 42 si. »

Noch ein paar Beispiele:

> A: Fährt der Bus über Bismarckplatz?
>   B: Nein, aber [über Willy-Brandt-Platz schon/über Willy-Brandt-Platz ja/über Willy-Brandt-Platz doch].
>
> A: Haben Sie rote Äpfel?
>   A: Nein, aber [grüne Äpfel ja/grüne Äpfel schon/grüne Äpfel doch].

Es könnte auch als Frage vorkommen:

> A: Fährt der Bus über Bismarckplatz?
>   B: Nein.
>   A: Aber [über Willy-Brandt-Platz schon/über Willy-Brandt-Platz ja/über Willy-Brandt-Platz doch]?
>   B: Ja.

Comment: Gibt es Bereiche in D/A/CH/FL/L/B/I, wo man eine Buslinie maskulin anspricht? Ich kenne auch nur die feminine Form *die 420*, wie von O.R.Mapper in seiner Antwort geschrieben. Ich würde sonst den Artikel umeditieren …

Comment: Ja, in Wien zum Beispiel. Wobei dort die Buslinien ein A oder B nachgestellt haben (13A, 95B,...) aber auch Strassenbahnlinen werden durchaus maskulin bezeichnet (z.B. der 5er)

Comment: @wastl: "der 5er" ist ja aber was anderes als "der 5". Ersteres klingt auch für mich natürich, Letzteres einfach nur falsch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A: Fahren alle Busse von dieser Haltestelle über Hauptbahnhof?

Die passende Antwort, um auszudrücken, dass zwar nicht alle Busse über den Hauptbahnhof fahren, aber die Linie 42 (die vielleicht gerade abfahrbereit ist) doch dort vorbeifährt, ist:

> B: Nein, aber die 42 schon.

Würde die Linie 42 *nicht* am Hauptbahnhof vorbeifahren, könnte die Antwort folgendermaßen auf den gerade vor Ort befindlichen Bus Bezug nehmen:

> B: Nein, auch die 42 nicht.

Begründung: [Martin Schwehla](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/13762/martin-schwehla) führt in [seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22792/5999) durchaus richtig aus, dass streng genommen ein einzelnes Beispiel einer Buslinie, die über Hauptbahnhof fährt, die Aussage, dass nicht alle Linien dort vorbeifahren, nicht einschränkt. Im vorliegenden Fall wird jedoch nicht die generelle Aussage, dass nicht alle Busse über den Hauptbahnhof fahren, eingeschränkt, sondern die Erwartung, dass, wenn nicht alle Busse dort vorbeifahren, der momentan abfahrbereite Bus wohl nicht ausgerechnet einer der Busse sein wird, die nun doch dort vorbeifahren.

---

Ich habe übrigens "der 42" durch "die 42" ersetzt. Das mag regional unterschiedlich sein, aber hier in Südwestdeutschland ist "der 42" ungebräuchlich. Es ist entweder "die [Linie/Nummer] 42" oder "der 42er[-Bus]".

Comment: Die Frage war aber nicht "Fahren alle Buslinien ..." sondern "Fahren alle Busse... ". Deswegen muss die Antwort entweder das "der" aufnehmen, oder "Linie" dazusetzen, sonst klingt es wie eine falsche Korrektur.

Comment: @userunknown: Wo ich lebe, ist es vollkommen normal zu sagen: "Welcher Bus kommt da?" - "Die 42." Die Formulierung "der 42" klingt für mich falsch, aber das könnte wie gesagt eine regionale Besonderheit sein. Ansonsten bietet sich aber natürlich, wie im letzten Absatz vermerkt, auch die Formulierung "der 42er" an, bei der dann das "der" erhalten bleibt.

Answer (score 7):

Die logische Antwort auf die Frage "Fahren alle Busse..." kann nicht "Nein, aber..." sein, da es ja kein Widerspruch zur Verneinung ist, dass nur ein Bus über den Hauptbahnhof fährt. Die folgerichtige Antwort wäre deshalb:

> Nein, *nur* die Linie 42 fährt über den Hauptbahnhof.

"Nein, aber..." wäre eine Einschränkung der Verneinung, im Sinn von:

> Nein, nicht alle Busse, aber alle Straßenbahnen.

Comment: Ich wollte nicht andeuten, dass nur die Linie 42 über Hauptbahnhof, sondern einfach diesen Bus als Möglichkeit anbieten, z.B. weil er gerade an der Haltestelle ist.

Comment: Ich wollte nicht andeuten, dass nur die Linie 42 über Hauptbahnhof fährt, sondern einfach diesen Bus als Möglichkeit anbieten, z.B. weil er gerade an der Haltestelle ist. Für mich waren "nicht alle Busse, aber wenigstens der 42" und "nicht alle Busse, aber alle Strassenbahnen" gleichwertig, also nicht logisch gleichwertig aber von der Satzkonstruktion her, weil das so auf französisch ist. Anscheinend ist das nicht so auf deutsch. Vielleicht gibt es keine deutsche Sprachwendung, die alle meine Beispiele umfassen kann.

Comment: @user3423952 Das ist wieder die Frage der Verstärkung im direkten Gespräch, als Signal, wenn man auf etwas besonders hinweisen will, in der Art einer doppelten Verneinung, die ja auch nicht auf der Sachebene, sondern auf der Appellebene wirken soll: "Nein, alle nicht, aber (Wechsel der Ebene) dieser Bus fährt zufällig gerade zum Hauptbahnhof".

Answer (score 3):

In deinem Beispiel - wenn man eine Ausnahme beschreiben will - verwendet man normalerweise das Wort "außer":

> Nein, außer der 42. ("No, but the 42 does. / No, except for the 42")

Wenn du eine Alternative ausdrücken willst, benutzt man "sondern":

> Nicht die 14, sondern die 42 fährt vom Hauptbahnhof.

Comment: Auch hier gilt: Dass nur ein Bus über den Hauptbahnhof fährt, ist keine Ausnahme von der Tatsache, dass nicht alle fahren, sondern die Bestätigung. Eine Ausnahme wäre es von der Behauptung, dass kein Bus über den Hauptbahnhof fährt, aber z.B. auch: "Nicht alle Busse fahren über den Hauptbahnhof, außer am Sonntag" (was natürlich bei diesem Beispiel nicht sehr sinnvoll ist).

Answer (score 1):

Zur Linie 42 haben alle ausreichend etwas beigetragen.

Zur Frage nach den Äpfeln:

> Haben Sie rote Äpfel?
>   **Entweder:** Nein [wir haben keine roten Äpfel], aber [wir haben] grüne [Äpfel].
>   **Oder:** Nein, [wir haben] nur grüne [Äpfel].

(auslassbare Satzbestandteile in eckigen Klammern.)

Zum Bismarckplatz:

> Fährt der Bus über [[den]](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/regionale-verbreitung-von-ich-bin-hauptplatz) Bismarckplatz?
>   **Entweder:** Nein, aber über [den] Willy-Brandt-Platz. (wenn Busse entweder über den Bismarck- oder über den Willy-Brandt-Platz fahren.)
>   **Oder:** Nein, nur über [den] Willy-Brandt-Platz. (wenn alle Busse über den Willy-Brandt-Platz fahren, aber manche zusätzlich auch über den Bismarckplatz, der in der gleichen Richtung liegt.)

Die Konstruktion als Frage zu formulieren ist grundsätzlich auch möglich:

> Fährt die Tram über [die] Leisewitzstraße?
>   Nein.
>   Aber über [den] John-F-Kennedy-Platz?
>   Ja.

Das würde ich so fragen, egal ob ich erwarte, dass alle Trams über den John-F-Kennedy-Platz fahren, oder ob ich erwarte, dass nur bestimmte dort entlangfahren.