# »Lass mal McDonald's gehen.«

Tags: grammaticality, personal-pronoun, teen-slang, ellipsis, objects

Ich habe heute in der Schule folgenden Satz gehört:

> Lass mal McDonald’s gehen.

Ist der grammatikalisch korrekt?

Müsste es nicht eigentlich heißen:

> Lass *uns* mal *in den* McDonald’s gehen.

Comment: _Lassma’ Meckes geh’n!_ u.ä. ist ziemlich normale Umgangssprache in bestimmten Bereichen und Gruppen, vgl. auch [Kiezdeutsch bzw. Kanaksprak](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanak_Sprak), wobei ich das Phänomen nicht darauf beschränkt sehen würde, sondern es allgemeiner evtl. regional beschränkt der Umgangs- oder Jugendsprache zurechnen würde.

Comment: Related: [...„ich bin Hauptplatz”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/regionale-verbreitung-von-ich-bin-hauptplatz/22759#22759)

Comment: "Ich geh' bei Aldi" - "**zu** Aldi" - "watt, schon nach acht?"

Comment: Der Apostroph steht im Deutschen als Auslassungszeichen. Wenn man wörtliche Rede wiedergibt markiert man den Sprecher nicht dadurch, dass man dessen typischen Schreibfehler wiedergibt.

Comment: Informativer Audiobeitrag: http://www.sprachschach.de/lassma-jetzt-was-uber-kiezdeutsch-schreiben-musstu-dann-aber-auch-lesen/

Comment: @userunknown Dein Kommentar ist wie so oft kryptisch, weil nicht zu sehen ist, worauf du dich beziehst.

Comment: @tofro: Auf mein Edit.

Comment: hat so viel Niveau wie "Ich Hunger!!!"

Comment: @userunknown: Der Apostroph steht da, weil er bereits im (englischen) Namen dieses Etablissements (McDonald’s) enthalten ist. Dort wiederum steht er, weil es eine übliche Benennung von Gaststätten u. Ä. in dieser Sprache ist. Letztere hat kein grammatikalisches Analogon im Deutschen: Man würde eine Kneipe nicht einfach *Horsts* nennen, sondern höchstens *bei Horst.* Insbesondere hat der Genitiv in *McDonald’s* nichts mit der deutschen Grammatik zu tun und es ergibt daher auch keinen Sinn, ihn im Rahmen der deutschen Rechtschreibregeln zu interpretieren und deshalb den Apostroph zu streichen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ambitioniert, aber falsch, siehe Kaiser's.

Comment: Kaisers war mE keine Kneipe.

Comment: @Jan Mäcces ist auch keine Kneipe, wenn ich mich recht entsinne. Sprich: Wir sollten es auf einer höheren Ebene betrachten, etwa "Gastronomiebetriebe".

Comment: Die Präposition, die vor dem Ziel genannt wird, ist übrigens nicht überall gleich: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f10c-e/

Answer (score 16):

Der Satz ist durchaus korrektes Deutsch, bedeutet aber etwas anderes als das, was der Sprecher wahrscheinlich sagen wollte.

> Lass mal McDonalds gehen

Könnte bedeuten, dass die Schüler ihren Englischlehrer Herrn Mc Donalds im Schrank eingesperrt haben, und der Sprecher den Angesprochenen auffordert, Herrn Mc Donalds jetzt gehen zu lassen.

Wenn der Sprecher den Angesprochenen auffordern wollte, *zu Mc Donalds* zu gehen, hätte er richtig gesagt

> Lass uns mal *zu* Mc Donalds gehen

Comment: Wenn man den Sinn der Frage verstanden hat, aber eine abseitige Möglichkeit findet, ihn wörtlich zu nehmen, und eine spitzfindige Antwort zu geben, sollte man dies in einem Kommentar tun.

Comment: @user unknown Nein, sollte man nicht und daran ist auch nichts "abseitiges" oder "spitzfindiges". Das ist das, was der Satz sagt. Und es ist wert, in einer Antwort zu erwähnen, dass der Satz so auch grammatikalisch richtig ist. Aus dem Kontext lässt sich *nicht* entnehmen, dass der Satz *nicht* wörtlich zu nehmen ist. (Vielleicht steckt Herr Mc Donalds ja immer noch im Schrank...). Und die *nicht wörtliche, aber mögliche* Auslegung des Satzes habe ich ja geliefert.

Comment: Wenn das korrektes Hochdeutsch ist, dann erklär mal das Genitiv-s. Der Satz ist korrektes Kiezdeutsch, nicht einfach falsch.

Comment: Das "s" ist kein Genitiv-s, sondern Bestandteil des englischen Namens. Der Satz ist vollkommen korrektes Deutsch.

Comment: In der ursprünglichen Frage stand aber ein Apostroph. Das habe ich getilgt, weil es im Deutschen falsch ist. Und der bekannte Name schottischer Herkunft ist McDonald. Das 's ist nur Teil der Wortmarke. Mir ist auch kein Mensch mit dem Namen McDonalds bekannt. Du versteigst Dich gerade.

Comment: @userunknown Mc Donalds ist ein durchaus gebräuchlicher Name (zugegeben nicht ganz so gebräuchlich wie das schottische Original ohne "S") aus dem englischen Sprachraum. Ob du einen davon kennst oder nicht, ist hier an sich nicht relevant.

Comment: In Österreich gibt es einen Politiker, der McDonald heißt. Er war noch vor wenigen Monaten der Generalsekretär der zweitgrößten Partei Österreichs: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_McDonald_(Politiker), dann ging er. (Man hat also McDonald gehen lassen.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Eben, McDonald, nicht McDonalds, vor allem nicht McDonald's, aber tofro erklärt uns gleich, dass das auch gebräuchlich sei :), nur um Recht zu behalten. Lassma stecken.

Comment: Wieder mal zu witzig die Antwort von @tofro.

Comment: Aber im ernst, was hätte das "mal" in deiner Bierernsten Auslegung zu suchen, können wir Herrn McD auch *zweimal* gehen lassen? Nein. Daher vertrete ich recht nüchtern die Ansicht, dass "mal" einst reflexives Element war, nunmehr kaum zu erkennen. Demnach ist auch "uns" überflüssig. Dass "zu" irregulär ausgelassen wird, mag im Kern richtig sein, kann aber dahinstehen, da *gehen* einfach die Bedeutung von *zu-gehen* übernimmt, welches wohl ohnehin nicht als zusammengehörig erkennbar ist, bzw. da *McD* als infinites Verb fungieren mag. Ich McDonalds, ich Facebook', ich Twitter. Du Nicht-Lustig.

Answer (score 10):

In einer deskriptiven Betrachtung der Sprache (die sich anschaut, welche Ausdrücke tatsächlich verwendet werden, und ob die jeweiligen Empfänger daran etwas auszusetzen haben) ist der Satz »Lass mal McDonald’s gehen« korrekt. Obgleich man ihn formalgrammatikalisch wie [Tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34326) auseinandernehmen kann, und dabei zu einem anderen Schluss kommt, ist es durchaus üblich vor allem unter Jugendlichen mit dieser verkürzten Phrase anzuzeigen, dass man die Restauration *Zum goldenen M* zu besuchen gedenkt.

In einer normativen Betrachtungsweise ist der Satz allerdings als falsch zurückzuweisen; er entspricht nicht den Richtlinien für gutes Deutsch. Denn nach den gemeinhin akzeptierten Regeln gilt:

- *lassen* in dieser Funktion erfordert in der Regel ein Akkusativobjekt *(wen* lassen wir etwas tun?)
- Lokaladverbiale müssen mit entsprechenden Präpositionen gekennzeichnet sein (wo? oder wohin?) und in ihrem Kasus muss ersichtlich sein, ob es sich um eine Bewegung oder einen Aufenthaltsort (nach grammatikalischen Gesichtspunkten) handelt.

Nach diesen Richtlinien für gutes Deutsch muss es – wie die anderen Antworten schon gesagt haben – folgendermaßen lauten:

> Lass uns mal zu McDonald’s gehen.

---

Übrigens mag mancher einwenden, dass der Beispielsatz schon außergewöhnlich lang, fast schon formell ist. Es kann auch noch viel kürzer werden:

> Gehen wir McDonald’s (oder: Mäcces).

Answer (score 9):

Der Satz ist nicht korrekt oder zumindest kein gutes Deutsch.
Richtig oder jedenfalls besser wäre

> Lass(t) uns mal in den McDonald's gehen.

oder

> Lass(t) uns mal in das / ins  McDonald's gehen.

oder

> Lass(t) uns mal zu McDonald's gehen.

Welche dieser Varianten man bevorzugt, hängt vermutlich davon ab als was man McDonald's vorrangig ansieht.
Ich persönlich würde zu McDonalds gehen.

Ich denke aber, dass der stark verkürzte Ausdruck

> Lass mal McDonald's gehen.

ähnlich wie

> Lass mal Kino gehen.

in Teilen der Jugendsprache durchaus üblich ist.

Comment: +1 für _zu McDonald's_

Comment: Ich habe 7 Jahre in Psychiatrie gearbeitet und keine Kinder oder jugendliche, "nicht mal krank", mit so ein Ausdruck gehört (auch nicht "lass mal Kino gehen": wohin geht es denn?)

Da fehlt mind. ein "uns ins" (Kino), oder "zum" bei McDonalds, sonst sind diese die die (irgendwo hin) gehen

Answer (score 3):

Das ist vereinfachte Sprache, also Jugendsprache. Wir sind zu faul um alles zu sagen.

Comment: Willkommen auf german.se! Könntest Du Deine Antwort ggf. mit Belegen oder zumindest einer Anekdote untermauern, die einerseits zeigen, dass _vereinfachte Sprache_ zwingend Jugendsprache sein muss, wie es Dein Gebrauch des Wörtchens _also_ suggeriert und andererseits wir _zu_ faul sind und dass Faulheit überhaupt eine Rolle spielt?

Comment: *proof by example*

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek *Also* ist ebenfalls Teil der Jugendsprache und wird häufig verwendet als: *Das was ich vorher gesagt habe war Schwachsinn, weil ich erst geredet und dann nachgedacht habe, also sage ich Dir jetzt, was ich eigentlich meinte*. Alles zu löschen und neu zu schreiben wäre auf dem Smartphone zu viel getippe.

Comment: @SiNa Wir waren als Jugendliche auch faul (und ich bin es gerne heute noch), aber trotzdem konnten wir vollständige Sätze sagen...

Comment: @tofro Gekauft! :)

Comment: Ich halte wenig davon, Antworten aufzublähen, um des Aufblähens willen. Im Gegenteil nerven mich lange Ausschweifungen die nicht zum Punkt kommen und den Kern der Aussage verbergen.

Answer (score 1):

Im Sommer habe ich einen etwa [dreißigminütigen Vortrag namens "Gehst Du Aldi" im SWR](http://mp3-download.swr.de/swr2/aula/2016/10/swr2-wissen-aula-20161016-wie-sich-die-deutsche-sprache-veraendert.12844s.mp3) dazu gehört. Die Autorin Diana Marossek hat darin Erkenntnisse [ihrer Doktorarbeit](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/handle/11303/4064) vorgetragen. Sie führt aus, dass es einerseits Interferenzen aus der türkischen Grammatik seien (Weglassen von Präposition und Artikel bei Ortsangaben), anderseits gäbe es dafür schon Belege aus dem frühen zwanzigsten Jahrhundert - es sei also auch ein Stadtsprachenphänomen.

Man sagt nicht "ich gehe *zu dem* McDonald's", sondern "*zum* McD". Normalerweise benutzt man also eine Kontraktion vor. Die Autorin spricht hier auch von **Kontraktionsvermeidung**.

Comment: Man kann aber auch *zu* McD gehen, wenn man McD als Eigennamen begreift und diesem keinen Artikel geben möchte, wie es im Norden üblich ist ;)

Comment: Wieso nicht **zum**?

Comment: Weil McD beinahe allgegenwärtig ist und somit kein zählbares Nomen, sondern ein indefiniter Zustand, der an vielen Orten erreicht werden kann, vgl *zu Geld kommen, zu Gott gehen*; in anderer Hinsicht--bzw ganz folgerichtig--ist es außerdem ein Eigenname, und die Praeposition daher nicht gegendert, vgl *zu Marko gehen, zu Gott gehen*; dagegen ist bspw *Geld* ansonsten definitiv zählbar, und bestimmt, daher *in's Geld kommen*, ähnlich *zum Himmel fahren*.  Eventuel spielt hier auch rein, dass neuter ursprünglich nicht mit *-m* gebeugt wurdem, vgl *wem* oder *was*, einst *wiu*, eben *zu* < *ziu*?

Comment: vgl dazu https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52613/dativ-der-fragepronomina-wer-und-was-wem-und-wam