# Dativ der Fragepronomina wer und was - wem und … *wam*?

Tags: grammatical-case, history

Eine kaiserliche Randnotiz zu einem [Telegramm des Reichskanzlers](https://archive.org/stream/diedeutschendoku00germ#page/221/mode/1up) lautet wie folgt:

> Woher ist das zu entnehmen? Aus dem mir vorgelegten Material nicht.

Dies versteht man natürlich problemlos, aber es klingt falsch oder zumindest wenig elegant, denn `entnehmen` steht mit dem Dativ. Der Kaiser hätte schreiben sollen:

> Welchem Material (*alternativ:* Welchen Unterlagen *oder* Welcher Quelle) ist das zu entnehmen? Dem mir vorgelegten Material nicht.

Das war ihm vielleicht zu umständlich für eine Randnotiz. Der springende Punkt ist jedenfalls, daß zwar `wer` vollständig dekliniert wird (wessen, wem, wen), `was` dagegen eine Lücke im Dativ aufweist (wessen, -, was). Gäbe es hier den Dativ `wam`, so hätte der Kaiser einfach schreiben können:

> Wam ist das zu entnehmen? Dem mir vorgelegten Material nicht.

Im lateinischen sind die Pronomina vollständig: quis/quid, cuius, cui, quem/quid, quo. (Im russischen auch: что Чего Чему Что Чем чём.) Warum nicht im deutschen? Wie sah es im mittelhochdeutschen und althochdeutschen aus? Was spricht dagegen, hier `wam` (siehe angehängten Nachtrag) oder auch `wem` zu benutzen? - Nachträgliche Klarstellung: Die Form `wam` ist *historisch nicht belegt* und nur *meiner Phantasie entsprungen*, wie die Form wohl lauten *könnte*.

---

Um auf die bisher eingetrudelten Kommentare einzugehen:

@Carsten: Die verlinkte Frage ist gleich, allerdings etwas unglücklich gestellt und von chirlu windschief beantwortet. Dafür ist die [Antwort von rogermue (bislang 0 Punkte)](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/28123/334) gut.

@tofro: Das Verb `entnehmen` wird in der Tat auch mit Präposition verwendet statt nur mit nacktem Dativ. Da hast du recht. Allerdings klingt es für meine Ohren recht unglücklich, sowohl in der kaiserlichen als auch in deiner Variante. Da würde ich eher fragen: Woraus hast du *ersehen* (statt *entnommen*), daß …

@Janka: *Wessen* ist Genitiv und paßt hier nicht. Dativ wird gesucht. *Wessen* und *wem* lassen beide an Personen denken.

Joachim Bumke, Einführung in die ältere deutsche Sprache - Materialien, Köln circa 1991 - Deklination des Fragefürwortes im Mittelhochdeutschen: wer/waz, wes, wem(e), wen/waz

Demnach wäre *wem* als Dativ von *was* hier das beste. Trotzdem unbefriedigend.

Das [DWB der Brüder Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW17265#XGW17265) <strike>(Lemma *wer*, dann Textsuche: *B. was — fragewort der sache*) schweigt sich leider auch über den fehlenden Dativ aus. Das hätt ich jetzt nicht gedacht.</strike> … enthält die Antwort, die ich übersehen habe, worauf David Vogt in den Kommentaren hinweist.

Es ist also eine defektive Deklination. Das ist hart, aber ich werde es überleben. - Nachtrag: Siehe Kommentar von David Vogt und ggf. Antwort.

Comment: Related (not the same): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/was-ist-was-im-dativ

Comment: Woraus hast du entnommen, dass "entnehmen" immer mit dem Dativ steht? Dieses Verb muss kein Dativ-Objekt haben.

Comment: @tofro: ich verstehe den Satz oben so, dass Lumi lediglich ausführt, dass im Zitat das `entnehmen` in einem Dativ-Konstrukt steht. Denn Lumis Vorschlag verwendet Genitiv & `entnehmen`. Daher sehe ich kein "immer mit Dativ".

Comment: Manch einer behilft sich mit *wessen*.

Comment: Guter Punkt. Das ist mir noch nie aufgefallen.

Comment: Das gute DWB schweigt sich natürlich nicht aus. Unter 2) *biegung* c) *der dativ* heißt es: *ein sachbezogener dativ des neutrums wird zwar gelegentlich angesetzt […] ist jedoch nicht üblich geworden*.

Comment: Wie kommst du auf "wam"? Dein Satz "Was spricht dagegen, hier wam ... zu benutzen?" klingt als gäbe es dieses Wort, oder als hätte es das Wort früher gegeben.

Comment: @DavidVogt - schreib das doch als Antwort, eine größere Autorität als das DWB gibt es ja wohl nicht. Damit wäre meine Frage beantwortet.

Comment: Wie ich schon oft anderswo kommentierte, ist es in solchen fragen angebracht, die Entwicklung der urindogermanischen Rekonstruktion zu betrachten. Zumindest ist der angeführte Vergleich zu L *quam* irreführend, da weder *qui* unser *wie*, noch *sto* unserem *wo* übersetzt, dem aber wohl entspricht, zumal *quam* weitaus mehr abdeckt als unser hypothetisches *?wam*, ganz zu schweigen von vulgärlateinischen Ausdrücken. Daher meine nicht ganz unberechtigte Gegenfrage: Weshalb denn nicht "woher", bzw wie ich sagen würde: *von wo* oder gängiger *woraus*, *woher -aus*? Sollte es etwa *wiuher* heißen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man beachte, daß die Fragepronomen *wer, was* in mehrfacher Hinsicht auffällig sind: Es gibt keinen Plural und keine femininen Formen; der Singular *wer* wird in Bezug auf Personen gebraucht, *was* in Bezug auf Sachen. Das wird oft damit begründet (z.B. von Gottsched, siehe unten), daß der Fragende nicht wissen könne, ob es um einen Mann, eine Frau oder mehrere Personen geht, und deshalb unterschiedslos *wer* gebraucht.

Laut Behaghel wird *wem* seit jeher nur in Bezug auf Personen gebraucht (*Deutsche Syntax* I, § [163](https://digisam.ub.uni-giessen.de/ubg-ihd-sob-a/content/pageview/633790)). Als Ersatzform für den fehlenden Dativ Neutrum konnte, solang es ihn noch gab, der Instrumental *wiu* stehen; später *was*. Mit Präpositionen ist letzteres bis heute möglich (wenn auch stigmatisiert): *Von was redest du?*

Eine Verwendung von *wem* als neutrale Form konnte sich nie durchsetzen. Das [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=29,71,43) schreibt dazu:

> [...] *ein sachbezogener dativ des neutrums wird zwar gelegentlich angesetzt* (was, wessen, wem, was GUEINTZ *sprachlehre* [1641] 57; *ebenso bei* SCHOTTEL *sprachkunst* [1641] 402 *und* GOTTSCHED *sprachkunst* [1748] 236), *er begegnet auch im älteren nhd.* (fragt ... wem des menschen hertz wer geleich H. SACHS 4, 150, 11 *lit. ver.*; weisz in wem [*worin*] die glori der seligen ... besteht ABRAHAM A S. CLARA *w.* 2, 131 *Strigl*), *ist jedoch nicht üblich geworden* [...]

Entgegen der Behauptung des DWB heißt es in Gottscheds *Grundlegung einer deutschen Sprachkunst* von 1748 auf S. [236](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10583647_00274.html?zoom=1):

> [D]och das unbestimmte Geschlecht hat nur die erste und vierte Endung. [Das sind Nominativ und Akkusativ.]